# How to get Short value from ArrayBuffer in javascript?

Tags: javascript, java

I have a ByteBuffer in java from which I am writing down first few values ,they are:

```
[-112, -37, 96, -28, -16, -28, -64, -25, 112, -30, -112, -29, 48, -28, 48,
 -30, -48, -28, 32, -27, 80, -31, -112, -29, 80, -31, -96, -28, -96, -28, 
 -112, -30, -96, -30, -16, -27, 16, -28, 48, -27, -64, -32, -112, -30, -32,
 -29, etc ,...]
```

And the code like `mybuffer.getShort()` returns value -9328, -7072, etc...
And according to Java API :

```
short java.nio.ByteBuffer.getShort()
```

Relative get method for reading a short value.

> Reads the next two bytes at this buffer's current position, composing
>   them into a short value according to the current byte order, and then
>   increments the position by two.
>
> Returns:The short value at the buffer's current position
>
> Throws:BufferUnderflowException - If there are fewer than two bytes
>   remaining in this buffer.

Upto here everything is fine, so the problem starts here and the problem is if I want to achieve the same in javascript, then how to do that?

I am using ArrayBuffer in javascript, but according to java API, they do some calculation which is very confusing.

Here is my javascript code:

```
var buf = new ArrayBuffer(res.length); // 2 bytes for each char
var bufView = new Uint16Array(buf); //buf is same as buffer in java ByteBuffer above.

for (var i = 0, strLen = res.length; i < strLen; i++) {
    bufView[i] = res.charCodeAt(i);
}
```

Comment: What is the problem with your code as it stands?

Comment: It is not clear what you want to do. Do you have StringBuffer in Java and you need to pass that data to JavaaScript?

Comment: How do you access the java array from javascript?

Comment: The first problem I see is you have set the length of your `ArrayBuffer` incorrectly. You need to do `var buf = new ArrayBuffer(res.length * 2);`.

Comment: Check this link http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html. I want to   have the similar type of ByteBuffer on client side(javascript) is it  clear now?.

Comment: Also I am more concerned about getShort method  of ByteBuffer.java what is the alternate of ByteBuffer.getShort() in javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just needed the same thing, and was pretty disappointed no answer was provided :D

played around a little bit with Scala then jumped to Java and finally got this
(of course this suits my needs, Java's implementation has different options..)

```
const getShort = (a,b) => a << 8 | b << 0
```

So If you have an Uint8Array([1,2,3,4,5,6])

```
const uiArr = new Uint8Array([1,2,3,4,5,6])
```

And you want to get first short just pass first two values from the array

```
const firstShort = getShort(uiArr[1], uiArr[0]) // in my case little endian 
const secondShort = getShort(uiArr[3], uiArr[2])
```

Comment: I had already done the same in javascript. Hope your post will help someone..Thanks